# � characters showing in HTTP response

Tags: html, meteor

When the page is downloaded in the browser, the network tab shows:
the request header `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
and the response header `Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`

This Meteor 1.4.2.3 server code uses the HTTP 1.2.10 package to download some page from the intent.
printing the content of the response to the console shows characters like � instead of single comma like those [image] and [image] and long dash.

The header of the code http request has
`"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1"`

In my code I have this line which is not the best solution.
`text = text.replace('�', '-');`

Any ideas how to properly display the correct human readable characters? thx

Comment: Have you tried using UTF-8 instead?

Comment: @DavidDylan No, Please give exact code line to try. thx

Comment: IDK. You barely gave any info to work with. It just looks like your charset is wrong. That's usually what it is when it can't identify a character.

Comment: @DavidDylan in order to try UTF-8 as you suggested. did you mean replace ISO-8859-1 with UTF-8 in the second parts of the value for Content-Type?